# Сортировка элементов в JSON по одному из значений

Tags: javascript, сортировка

требуется алгоритм, который смог бы отсортировать элементы в JSON по одному из значений объекта. Объяснил криво, приведу пример до, после:

```
//до
{
  "some_var2": {
    "some_var2_1": "test",
    "some_var2_2": 2
  },
  "some_var3": {
    "some_var3_1": "test",
    "some_var3_2": 3
  }
  "some_var": {
    "some_var1_1": "test",
    "some_var1_2": 1
  }
}
//после
{
  "some_var": {
    "some_var1_1": "test",
    "some_var1_2": 1
  },
  "some_var2": {
    "some_var2_1": "test",
    "some_var2_2": 2
  }
  "some_var3": {
    "some_var3_1": "test",
    "some_var3_2": 3
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  "some_var2": {
    "some_var2_1": "test",
    "some_var2_2": 2
  },
  "some_var3": {
    "some_var3_1": "test",
    "some_var3_2": 3
  },
  "some_var": {
    "some_var1_1": "test",
    "some_var1_2": 1
  }
}

function sortObj(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((acc, key) => ({...acc, [key]: obj[key]}), {})
}

console.log(sortObj(obj));
```

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!